# How to Toggle background image based on Image URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, toggle, background-image

I want to change a background image on click based upon the url of the DIV that I have clicked

My logic works as follows:

When a users clicks a div

```
 {

    If (Background URL = x)
    {
       change background url property to y
    }
    else
    {
       change background url property to x
    }
 }
```

Here is the code I used

HTML:

```
<div id="AccordionContainer" class="AccordionContainer">

    <div onclick="runAccordion(1);changeArrow(1)">
        <div class="AccordionTitle" id="Accordion1Title" onselectstart="return false;" onclick="changeArrow(1);" >
            Instructions
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Accordion1Content" class="AccordionContent">  
        <p>Enter in your search parameters</p>
    </div>

    <div onclick="runAccordion(2);">
        <div class="AccordionTitle" id="Accordion2Title" onselectstart="return false;" onclick="changeArrow(2);" >
            Colour
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Accordion2Content" class="AccordionContent">  
        [wpv-control field="cultivar-category" type="checkboxes" values="Dark Red" url_param="cultivar-category"]
    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
function changeArrow(index)
{
    var arrowID = "Accordion" + index + "Title";    

    var img = document.getElementById(arrowID),
    style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
    bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);


if (bi = "http://www.hadecobulbs.com/wp-content/themes/blankslate/img/accordian-title.png")
{
    document.getElementById(arrowID).style.background="url(http://www.hadecobulbs.com/wp-content/themes/blankslate/img/accordian-title-up.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById(arrowID).style.background="url(http://www.hadecobulbs.com/wp-content/themes/blankslate/img/accordian-title.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent";
}

}
```

However when I click on the Accordion(index)Title Div the image changes upon first click but when I click again the image does not change back. Why would this be the case? What am I missing here?

Comment: use two css classes and then, use javascript only to switch between those classes. `document.getElementById("your_element_id").className = "your_css_className"`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used Wezly's help combined with yours and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a number to the function you could pass the element itself using `this` which means you can reduce the amount of code you write considerably.

Call the function on your div like this

```
<div class="background_one" onClick="changeArrow(this)"> </div>
```

Using @d4rkpr1nc3's comment setup your css classes to change the background image like so

```
.background_one {
width:188px;
height:32px;
background-image:url('wp-content/themes/blankslate/img/accordian-title-up.png');
}

.background_two {
width:188px;
height:32px;
background-image:url('wp-content/themes/blankslate/img/accordian-title.png');
}
```

Then do something like this in your function

```
function changeArrow(element){

  var arrow = element;

    if(arrow.className == 'background_one'){

      arrow.className = 'background_two';

    } else {

      arrow.className = 'background_one';

    }

}
```

Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/QwELf/

Comment: I really appreciate your help! This worked beautifully and the reduction in code is a massive bonus.

Comment: Not a problem, be sure to mark answers as the accepted answer when you are happy they answer your question.